# Setting UIPickerView from NSArray Object

Tags: ios, ios7, uipickerview

I am trying to set the UIPicker View with the date for the last 20 Mondays. The array is filled with 20 Week Objects. e.g NSDate *weekDate=3/24/2014 NSString *weekDateString=Week of 3/24/2014.

When I set the rows initially it shows the first 5-6 rows correctly, when I try to scroll the picker is trying to set the title for the new rows it is displaying, but setTitle is logging (null) for the weekDateString. The list is still showing a count of 20, when I log the count in titleForRow.

If I set the NSArray just NSString there are no issues.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        _weeks = [Week getWeeks];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.title=@"Weeks";
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer insertSublayer:[LayoutColors getNavBarGradient:self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds] atIndex:1];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes
    = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]};

    int startYValue = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + HeaderHeight;
    int width = self.view.frame.size.width;
    _picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, startYValue, width/2, DATE_PICKER_HEIGHT)];
    _picker.delegate = self;
    _picker.dataSource = self;

    [self.view addSubview:self.picker];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    //One column
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    //set number of rows
    return _weeks.count;
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    Week *week = [_weeks objectAtIndex:row];
    return week.weekDateString;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code, so one is compelled to infer that there is probably something wrong with your model object, i.e. your `_weeks` array is not in fact correctly populated the way you think it is - the `weekDateString` is apparently missing for some of the Week objects. You should probably go back and look at how you are generating this array.

Comment: When Title for row is called in the first I just logged all the values for weekDateString and it shows all of the strings. Then when I scroll the past the 5 that are displayed, it is giving me (null) for the ones that aren't display.

Comment: Well, @bryc3krispies, you need to look at all your code. It sounds like you have other code - code that you didn't show in your question - that is destroying your `_weeks` array.

Comment: For example maybe you've made some mistake in an implementation of `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` that destroyed `_weeks`. I don't know because, whatever the problem is, it's in code you didn't show me.

Comment: I added the rest of the code, I am not calling pickerView:didSelectRow  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Well that was a stupid question. It was because the weekDateString was set to weak in the class Week. I guess thats what happens when you are new to iOS. So you are right the issue was in model object.

Comment: Elementary. "When you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth." The trick is learning to do that on your own.